# How to prevent malware from uploading for saving public images for the web?

Tags: node.js, image, security

I want to allow users of my website to save public image files using node.js. What should I do to follow best practices for safe image storage? How to prevent malware from uploading?

I currently control the following:

- check if the user is logged in
- size of images
- number of images
- type of images

I want to allow the following types of images to be saved:

```
image/gif              gif;
image/jpeg             jpeg jpg;
image/png              png;
image/svg+xml          svg svgz;
image/tiff             tif tiff;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp     wbmp;
image/webp             webp;
image/x-icon           ico;
image/x-jng            jng;
image/x-ms-bmp         bmp;
```

What else should I consider to prevent malware from uploading?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the details of how you will allow downloading and how you will do it, but a general answer can be made, assuming by "check if the user is logged in" that we are talking about a web page at one point of the process:

If the images are public, everybody can download it. You cannot prevent anyone that can actually see an image from downloading it (because at this point, the image has already been transmitted to the client's browser).

**Generally** (for those that didn't know already): never put online images that you don't want to spread over the web (or which have a copyright you have no right upon). "Convoluted solutions" like trying to disable right click on a web page to prevent download can only stop very beginners. If you want an image to be able to be displayed, it has to be accessible and therefore it's downloadable.

**What you can do**, stock photos websites usually work like this: only a bad quality preview of the picture (or with a big watermark over it) is public and is displayed on pages. The real full quality image is private and will be downloaded via direct file download when all your checks are verified.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I replaced the word `downloading` by `uploading`

Comment: Then I fear your question becomes either too broad or missing more focus, people just can't list all security measures that can be taken against any type of attack, it's a vast topic, and much can be said about the details of what you already have put in place, depending on details of your implementation. "malware" is maybe too vague here, each type of attack has its panel of solutions, for example you may protect your own upload script, but if the site/server has another flaw that allows someone to inject a script on your server, they could upload things with it..